# How to create a function in jS using Github Copilot and running that function in VS Code (OsX)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

This is sort of a two-part question. I'm trying to play around with Copilot and used the beginners tutorial to reproduce the code which looks like this.

```
// find all images without alternate text
// and give them a red border
function process() {
    var images = "cat_pics.html".getElementsByTagName("img")
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var image = images[i]
        if (image.alt == "") {
            image.style.border = "1px solid red"
        }
    }
}
```

There was only one change which was that changed the source of images to a local file.

However I ran this I received an error.

[Running] node "/Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/tempCodeRunnerFile.js"
/bin/sh: node: command not found

```
[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.008 seconds
```

The second question is specific to VS Code having switched to it from Sublime. I can see there are powerful tools but how would the debugger to get to the problem?

Comment: Did you install nodejs?

Comment: Why do you try to run browser-only code in nodejs?

Comment: Node.js wasn't installed so I'm going down the brew install x route